# Relay Modern subscriptions: returning record mutiple times incrementally

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-subscriptions

I am working on a very simple app which contains Posts and comments on those Posts. I have got

1) comment_mutation.js ( Server side - i am publishing the saved comment using pubsub). I have removed unnecessary code

```
   CommentCreateMutation: mutationWithClientMutationId({
        name: 'CommentCreate',
        inputFields: {
        },
        outputFields: {
            commentEdge: {
                type: GraphQLCommentEdge,
                resolve: async ({ comment, postId }) => {
                    // Publishing change to the COMMENT_ADDED subscription.
                    await pubsub.publish(COMMENT_SUB.COMMENT_ADDED, { commentAdded: commentEdge, postId });
                    return commentEdge;
                },
            },
        },
        mutateAndGetPayload: () => {
            // Save comment in DB
        },
    }),
```

2) CommentSubscription.js (server side) - getting the subscription and filtering it based on postId.

```
commentAdded: {
        type: GraphQLCommentEdge,
        args: {
            postId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
            ...connectionArgs,
        },
        subscribe:
            withFilter(
                () => pubsub.asyncIterator(COMMENT_SUB.COMMENT_ADDED),
                (payload, args) => payload.postId === args.postId
            ),
    },
```

Server side is working very good. Whenever any comment is created it publishes the result to subscrition. Subscription catches it and displays the results.

> Now the client side:

1) CommentMutaton.js - client side. Whenever user himself creates a comment on client side (react native) it is updating the store very well.

```
const mutation = graphql`
    mutation CommentCreateMutation($input:CommentCreateInput!) {
        commentCreate(input: $input) {
            commentEdge {
                __typename
                cursor
                node {
                    id
                    _id
                    text
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;

const commit = (environment, user, post, text, onCompleted, onError) => commitMutation(
    environment, {
        mutation,
        variables: {
            input: { userId: user._id, userName: user.userName, postId: post._id, text },
        },
        updater: (store) => {
            // Update the store
        },
        optimisticUpdater: (store) => {
            // Update the store optimistically
        },
        onCompleted,
        onError,
    },
);
```

2) CommentSubscription.js (client side)

```
const subscription = graphql`
    subscription CommentAddedSubscription($input: ID!) {
        commentAdded(postId: $input) {
            __typename
            cursor
            node {
                id
               _id
               text
               likes
               dislikes
            }
        }
    }
`;

const commit = (environment, post, onCompleted, onError, onNext) => requestSubscription(
    environment,
    {
        subscription,
        variables: { 
            input: post._id,
        },
        updater: (store) => {
            const newEdge = store.getRootField('commentAdded');
            const postProxy = store.get(post.id);
            const conn = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(
               postProxy,
               'CommentListContainer_comments',
            );
            ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeAfter(conn, newEdge);
        },
        onCompleted,
        onError,
        onNext,
    }
);

export default { commit };
```

Problem is on client side. Whenever i create a comment on server side I can see the first comment rightly on client side. When i send another comment on server side i can see 2 same comments on client side. When i send comment third time i can see 3 same comments on client side. Does it mean:

> every time comment_mutation.js (on server side) runs it create a new
>   subscription besides existing one. That is the only logical
>   explanation i can think of.

I commented out the updater function of CommentMutation.js (on client side) but still seeing this error. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the pubsub.publish trigger only once every time you create a comment?

Comment: Yes it triggers only once when a comment is created. I put console.log to confirm that.

Comment: Does the subscribing component get mounted and unmounted with every created comment?

Comment: No. It does not get mounted or unmounted with every created comment.